# NullPointerException on rotateThreadedDelayed with AdWhirlLayout

Tags: android, adwhirl

What cause a `NullPointerException` on `rotateThreadedDelayed` with an `AdWhirlLayout`?

Here is the stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.rotateThreadedDelayed(wHAT .java:237)
at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.handleAd(AdWhirlLayout.java:210)
at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.access$3(AdWhirlLayout.java:205)
at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$HandleAdRunnable.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:390)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem for quite long time. It seems like there is not solution for now, except download source code of Adwhirl SDK for Android and fix this NPE by yourself. 
The fix itself is pretty straightforward and already discussed here: http://groups.google.com/group/adwhirl-users/msg/b9641da44fa0f0ce

Here is fixed code:

```
public void rotateThreadedDelayed() {
    int cycleTime = 30; 
    if( extra != null ) { 
        cycleTime = extra.cycleTime; 
    } 
    Log.d(AdWhirlUtil.ADWHIRL, "Will call rotateAd() in " + cycleTime + " seconds"); 
    scheduler.schedule(new RotateAdRunnable(this), cycleTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
}
```